# Display progress of a long running Python task in Django

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I currently have a typical Django structure set up for a project and one web application.

The web application is set up so that a user inputs some information, and this information is taken as the input to run a Python program.

This python program sometimes can take quite a while to finish (grabbing things from the web and doing some text mining scoring) - sometimes it can take multiple minutes to load.

On the command line, this program would periodically display where it was in the process (it'd first say how many things it found to score against, then it'd say where in the number of things found it is in the scoring process), which was very useful. However, when I moved this over to a Django set up, I no longer have this capability (at least, not in the same way since now this is sent to log files).

The way I set it up is that there is an input view, and then a results view. The results view takes the input and runs the Python program. It won't display the results until the entire program is run. So on the user side, the browser just sits there for sometimes minutes before the results are displayed. Obviously, this is not ideal.

Does anyone know of the best way to bring status information on a task to Django?

I've looked into Celery a little bit, but I think since I'm still a beginner in Django that I'm confusing myself with some of the documentation. For instance: even if the task is sent off asynchronously to a worker, how does the browser grab the current state of the program?? Also, consistent documentation seems to be lacking for celery on Django (I've seen people set up celery many different ways on their Django projects).

I would appreciate any input here, I've been stuck on this for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion is to psychologically separate celery from django when you start to think of the two. They can run in the same environment, but celery is to asynchronous processes what django is to http requests.

Also remember that celery is unlike diango in that it requires other services to function; a message broker. So by using celery you will increase your architectural requirements.

To address you specific use case, you'll need a system to publish messages from each celery task to a message broker and your web client will need to subscribe to those messages.

There's a lot involved here, but the short version is that you can use Redis as your celery message broker as well as your pub/sub service to get messages back to the browser. You can then use e.g diango-redis-websockets to subscribe the browser to the task state messages in redis

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've been using RabbitMQ. Any advantage for Redis over RabbitMQ?

Also, are you familiar with jobtastic? policystat.github.io/jobtastic/ 

Would that be useful?

Comment: RabbitMQ vs Celery is very hard to answer without knowing more about your setup, expected task frequency etc. However, IMO, Redis is easier to setup and manage and can do many jobs out of the box: act as your celery message broker, pub/sub and web cache. Jobtastic looks good, but I've never used it; a quick glance suggests it might be exactly what you need, but personally, I'd rather achieve your goal without it (less "magic", more explicit).

Comment: This is on a Linux Apache server (development environment on a Windows machine).

I have installed Celerey and Django-Celery. RabbitMQ is the backend messenger service that I've been using (as opposed to Redis - I could switch to it if the advantages are worthwhile). 

I tried working with JobTastic, but I got stuck - keep getting an error when one tries to call .delay_or_fail on the JobTastic class. I even used the exact example code from their site, and it still failed. Perhaps it's no longer supported with the current versions of Celery and Django. 

I'll look at setting this up via Celery.